# Where could I call callback function inside the body of covering function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I want to declare a javascript function getMyAttribute() with call back so that I could use it like following manner

```
var result = getMyAttribute(1, 2, function(){
    console.log(result);
});
```

I have a question, where could I call the callback function inside the getMyAttribute()?

```
function getMyAttribute(num1, num2, callback){
    // where should I call the callback function in this block ?
    var result = num1+num2;// this is just an example of function processing to get result. In practice, it may be more complex, or in an async way
    return result;
}
```

I am inspired from Angular code, in angular, I could do a code like this one

```
var pager = Product.get({p:pageIndex},function(){
        $scope.showProducts(pager);
});
```

How could angular implement this one ?

Comment: Before you return that result. When do you want that callback be called, actually? If you want it be called after return, add a `setTimeout` then.

Comment: Why do you need a `callback` if the function is returning the result in a synchronous way? Anyway, what you're probably looking for is `callback(result);` *after* your `var result = num1+num2;` line.

Comment: If it's not obvious where to put it (e.g. if `+` was async and took a callback), then you shouldn't use a callback and just `return` the result.

Comment: @haim770: There are many situations where callbacks are useful for synchronous code. One example that I'm sure we're all familiar with is `forEach()`.

Comment: @slebetman, You're right. I should have added that the callback is unhelpful for this particular need.

Answer (score 0):

We normally uses a callback when we don't know when a process will occur like in a asynchronous method like ajax, so in such cases we can't return any value(In such cases we will call the callback once the result is ready). Or in cases(as pointed out by @slebetman) where a collection has to be processed and we need to do something on each item like in `each()` callback

Note: Your current method doesn't really require a callback based implementation as there is no async operation in it.

So the implementation of the method using callback will be

```js
getMyAttribute(1, 2, function(result) {
  snippet.log('got the result: ' + result);
});

function getMyAttribute(num1, num2, callback) {
  //since a callback is expected, dont return the value, call the callback with the value
  var result = num1 + num2;
  callback(result);
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<!-- To show result in the dom instead of console, only to be used in the snippet not in production -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not only async. Also for processing collections (arrays, objects) for example `[].map()` or `[].forEach()`. Also for function factories etc.